# How to use locks with server-side objects in flask/socketio application?

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, locking

I have a server which hosts a two-player game online. It is a turn-based game. The server maintains a list of all the ongoing games (each game is represented as an object of my class `Game`). The `Game` class manages each game, including whose turn it is. Players communicate with each other by calling sockets on the server (e.g., a `Movement` socket), which then grab the game object associated with the player's game, and operate on that game object.

One of the players is actually automated, and running as a separate process on the server side (though it communicates the same way a browser-based player would). However, this means the protocol for getting this player to send `Movement` is: (1) server sends a message to the automated player process requesting an action, (2) automated player responds with an action (potentially ~1 second later) to the `Movement` socket, and then (3) the server processes this action (e.g., forwards it to the other player).

The game is turn-based, but I need to allow players to interrupt each other's turn. Specifically: pressing a special key should end the other player's turn. The interrupting player's game triggers the `Cancel` socket on the server, which grabs the game object, and then should switch turn control to the other player (and notify the other player their turn has ended).

However, I don't want the server to process a `Cancel` while it's waiting for a `Movement` from the automated player. This can break the synchronization between the two players and the server. I tried addressing this by adding a `threading.Lock` attribute as a member of the `Game` class. So my `Game` class looks like this:

```
import threading
class Game:
  def __init__(self):
    self.lock = threading.Lock()

  def process_movement(self):
    # Do some stuff here, like forward the message to the other player
    pass

  def process_cancel(self):
    # Do some stuff here, like end the current player's turn, and send the message to the other player
    pass

  def request_movement(self):
    # Acquire the lock here...
    self.lock.acquire()
    emit('requestAction', room=self.automated_player_room())

  def is_automated_players_turn(self):
    # Returns bool according to if it's the automated player's turn
    pass
```

And every time either of those two sockets are called, they acquire the game's lock, operate on the object, and then release the lock. For example, the `Cancel` socket:

```
@socketio.on('Cancel')
def cancel():
  game_obj: Game = get_game()
  game_obj.lock.acquire()
  game_obj.process_cancel()
  game_obj.lock.release()
```

and for the `Movement` socket:

```
@socketio.on('Movement')
def movement():
  game_obj: Game = get_game()
  game_obj.process_movement()

  # Release the lock here
  game_obj.lock.release()
  if game_obj.is_automated_player_turn():
    game.request_action()
```

However, I am noticing that for some games, the lock is violated: even though the `Movement` socket hasn't yet been called, so the lock should be locked, `Cancel` can still proceed to call `process_cancel()`. Unfortunately, I actually can't replicate this error myself; only other people playing the game have been able to replicate it, and I can't figure out the conditions under which it happens.

Am I using locks correctly? Why would the lock be violated if this is my setup?

Thanks!

Edit: I heard that python doesn't seem to guarantee much about threads which acquire but don't release locks. Now looking for suggestions on a better data structure I should use.